# Volley getting SSLHandshakeException in android 5.0+ devices

Tags: android, performance

I am getting below error

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:"

in Android 5.0+ devices while trying to access a https url.

Comment: It is working fine in lesser version of android 5.0.. But not in older than 5.0